# Issue with a day of the week program

Tags: python, dayofweek

For a python class, we were required to create a program that allows the user to input a date between 1900 and 2100 and it will calculate the day of the week.

My code is working for all dates except January and February of 1900 and I don't know why.

I've been looking at it for too long and I can't tell whats wrong.

```
def main():
    #Getting the main inputs from the user
    year = int(input('Enter year: '))
    #While loops used to check if inputs are valid
    while((year > 2100) or (year < 1900)):
    year = int(input('Enter year: '))

    a = int(input('Enter month: '))

    while((a > 12) or (a < 1)):
        a = int(input('Enter month: '))

    b = int(input('Enter day: '))

    #check if year is a leap year
    is_leap = (year % 400 == 0) or ((year % 100 !=0) and (year % 4 ==0))



    #this next block checks to make sure that the day entered is valid for the month
    if (a == 1) or (a == 3) or (a == 5) or (a == 7) or (a == 8) or (a == 10) or      (a == 12):
        while ((b < 1) or (b > 31)):
            b = int(input('Enter day: '))
    elif (a == 4) or (a == 6) or (a == 9) or (a == 11):
        while ((b < 1) or (b > 30)):
            b = int(input('Enter day: '))
    else:
    #this checks if the year is a leap year and whether or not the day is valid
        if (a == 2) and is_leap:
            while ((b < 1) or (b > 29)):
                b = int(input('Enter day: '))
        if (a == 2) and not is_leap:
            while ((b < 1) or (b > 28)):
                b = int(input('Enter day: '))

#separating the century from the year
if (year > 1999):
    d = 20
elif (year < 2000):
    d = 19
#slicing the year of the century off the total year
c = (year - (d *100))


#to make the algorithm work, the month number and year must be changed for certain months
if (a >= 3):
    a = (a-2)
elif (a == 1):
    a = 11
    c = (c-1)
elif (a == 2):
    a = 12
    c = (c-1)


# Now for the computations

w = (13 * a-1)//5
x = c//4
y = d//4
z= w + x + y + b + c - 2 * d
r = z % 7
r = (r+7)%7

#and for the final variables and printing

if (r == 0):
    day = 'Sunday.'
elif (r == 1):
    day = 'Monday.'
elif (r == 2):
    day = 'Tuesday.'
elif (r == 3):
    day = 'Wednesday.'
elif (r == 4):
    day = 'Thursday.'
elif (r == 5):
    day = 'Friday.'
else:
    day = 'Saturday'

print('The day is',day,)


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the only issue, but for the months january and february you have a computation like below -

```
elif (a == 1):
    a = 11
    c = (c-1)
elif (a == 2):
    a = 12
    c = (c-1)
```

But for `1900` c is 0 and hence with this you are setting c to `-1` . And the `d` is still pointing to `19`. I believe this could be causing the issue.

After changing that part to the below , it started to work for `1900` jan and feb -

```
if (a >= 3):
    a = (a-2)
elif (a == 1):
    a = 11
    c = (c-1)
    if c == -1:
        c = 99
        d = d - 1
elif (a == 2):
    a = 12
    c = (c-1)
    if c == -1:
        c = 99
        d = d - 1
```

Example -

Run1 -

```
Enter year: 1900
Enter month: 1
Enter day: 5
The day is Friday.
```

Run2 -

```
Enter year: 1900
Enter month: 2
Enter day: 2
The day is Friday.
```